# Matplotlib graph line not displaying?

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib

Very simple program. Not sure why the graph line isn't displaying. Everything else is updating/displaying fine.

I'm just trying to model my cpu frequency vs time.

Anyone know why my line isn't displaying? I've looked around but can't seem to find a similar issue.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style


# Function to obtain CPU frequency from file 'cpuinfo'
def getfreq():

    with open('/proc/cpuinfo', 'r') as f:

        for line in f.readlines():

            lineSplit = line.split(':')

            if len(lineSplit) == 2:

                lineSplit[0] = lineSplit[0].strip()
                lineSplit[1] = lineSplit[1].strip()

                if lineSplit[0] == "cpu MHz":
                    frequency = float(lineSplit[1])
                    return frequency


style.use('fivethirtyeight')
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

time = 0

def animate(i):

    global time

    frequency = getfreq()

    xs = []
    ys = []

    xs.append(float(time))
    time = time + 1
    ys.append(frequency)
    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xs, ys)


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why do you clear the axis ?

Comment: Because the framework given did that. Removing that line doesn't help. @Patol75

Comment: This example should help you: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/animate_decay.html#sphx-glr-gallery-animation-animate-decay-py

Comment: You're plotting a single point each time. But a line with a single point is not shown (you need two points for a line to be drawn). I would suspect that what you really want is to show all the points and a line between them all. Hence define `xs` and `ys` **outside** of the function.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest That helped immensely, thank you :)